# Will my AsyncTask die when listener stop working in this android firebase code?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

So I added the `ChildEventListener` and `ValueEventListener` into an `AsyncTask`.
Figure this way main ui thread wont be bothered. The code below works grate but the question is what happens when I terminate the listeners in my down below `exitFirebase()` method?

When the `AsyncTask` start it go trough `doInBackground()` adding FireBase listeners and then go trough `onPostExecute()` and seemingly exit but the listeners is keeping the `AsyncTask` alive right..

what happens when I terminate the listeners?

```
   /**
     * Typically when user sign in or app start
     */
    public void userSigneIn() {
        // start listening
        asyncTaskUserAddressHistory().execute();
    }


    public AsyncTask asyncTaskUserAddressHistory() {
        AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() {

            /**
             * The User history address child event listener.
             * This is only used when app first install or user wipe data
             */
            ChildEventListener userHistoryAddressChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String prevKey) {
                    // do the work and continue listen
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, String prevKey) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    // remove listener
                    ChildEventListener listener = mChildListenerMap.get(onCancel);
                    onCancel.removeEventListener(listener);
                    // start over
                    startListenForUserAddressHistory();
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot snapshot, String prevKey) {
                }
            };

            ValueEventListener userHistoryAddressvalueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // get history for current user
                    if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() != 0) {
                        // do the work and start over
                        startListenForUserAddressHistory();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    // remove listener
                    ValueEventListener listener = mValueListenerMap.get(onCancel);
                    onCancel.removeEventListener(listener);
                    // start over
                    startListenForUserAddressHistory();
                }
            };

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
                // If local user don´t have any history start the ChildEventListener.
                if (HistoryManager.getInstance().getHistoryItems(mFireBaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).size() == 0) {
                    // Local cache of address history is empty get all address history for this user and start listen for new items
                    final Query query = ref.child(USER_HISTORY).limitToLast(LIMIT);
                    onCancel = query.getRef();
                    mChildListenerMap.put(query.getRef(), userHistoryAddressChildEventListener);
                    query.addChildEventListener(userHistoryAddressChildEventListener);

                } else {
                    // If client have history start the ValueEventListener.
                    // Typically this is not the first time app starts.
                    startListenForUserAddressHistory();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                super.onPostExecute(o);
                // This runs and listeners are alive
            }

            /**
             * Start listen for nye entries based on that server have entries<br>
             * and client have entries, typically this is not the first time App starts.
             * This uses a ValueEventListener.
             */
            private void startListenForUserAddressHistory() {
                // Local history is not empty so we must go get only new items
                final HistoryItem historyItem = HistoryManager.getInstance()
                        .orderHistoryByDateAndGetNewest(mFireBaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                final Query query = ref
                        .child(USER_HISTORY)
                        .child(mFireBaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .child(UserHistory.ADDRESS_HISTORY)
                        .orderByKey()
                        .startAt(historyItem.getPushKey());
                mValueListenerMap.put(query.getRef(), userHistoryAddressvalueEventListener);
                skipStartAtKey = historyItem.getPushKey();
                onCancel = query.getRef();
                query.addValueEventListener(userHistoryAddressvalueEventListener);
            }
        };
        return task;
    }

    /**
     * App is closing or User has signed out
     * Called from both onClose() and userSignedOut()
     */
    private void exitFirebase() {
        if (userLogger != null)
            userLogger.log(USER_SIGNED_OUT);
        // Close ChildEventListener(s)
        for (Map.Entry<DatabaseReference, ChildEventListener> entry : mChildListenerMap.entrySet()) {
            DatabaseReference ref = entry.getKey();
            ChildEventListener listener = entry.getValue();
            if (listener != null && ref != null)
                ref.removeEventListener(listener);
        }
        // Close ValueEventListener(s)
        for (Map.Entry<DatabaseReference, ValueEventListener> entry : mValueListenerMap.entrySet()) {
            DatabaseReference ref = entry.getKey();
            ValueEventListener listener = entry.getValue();
            if (listener != null && ref != null)
                ref.removeEventListener(listener);
        }
        if (userAuthListener != null)
            mFireBaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(userAuthListener);
        userLogger = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I added the ChildEventListener and ValueEventListener into an
>   AsyncTask.

There is no need to use `AsyncTask` for implementing Firebase operations. Firebase is already optimized. So you don't need to use a background thread for performing network-related operations using firebase.

The callbacks for Firebase listeners is executed on the main UI thread only. However, if you have a large amount of task to be performed then you can use the AsyncTask inside the callback itself.

Comment: The `onDataChange()` method is actually running on  UI thread

Comment: @ErikHellberg The callbacks for your Firebase listeners is executed on the main UI thread.

Comment: I though if I start the listeners in the `doInBackground()` the FireBase callbacks would also happen in background thread

Comment: @ErikHellberg you can use the AsyncTask inside the callback itself if you have a large amount of work to be performed

Comment: I actually did that but the `onChildAdded()` is triggered once for each existing child and that created many many `AsyncTasks` . Ok thanks for clearing this out I must solve it your way I really like multi threading on Christmas eve :)

Comment: Merry Christmas @ErikHellberg :)